# verification of 3NF table

Tags: database-design, normalization

I have designed this table and wanted to find out if it is 3NF, I would assume it is since all the non-primary key frelds are not transitively dependent on primary key, but wanted your thoughts, if i am missing something
Patient_Id : ID (PK)
Patient_name : Name
Patient_DOB : Date
Patient_Gender: GenderType
Patient_address : Address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks fine, except the `Patient_address` column, which should be stored in a different table. Here is an example:

```
Patients(ID, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, MainAddressId);
Addresses(Id, Street, Number, ..., PatientId);
```

This way, each patient can have more than one address, while you can still set an address as the main address (in the MainAddressId).

Comment: Thanks a lot npclaudiu! can I pleae ask you to check another table for me. I have this table , Test_Booking Booking_Id: ID (pk) Test_Id: ID (fk to Test_master) Patient_ID:ID(fk to Patient) Gp_ID:ID(fk to GP) Book_Date: Date    , is this 3NF (this one I am a bit unsure)

Comment: From the information provided, I understand that a test (stored in Test_master) can have zero or more test bookings associated (stored in Test_Booking), and each test booking has a date, a patient and a GP. If this is the intended result, then the schema is valid.